# Export image fails across the antimeridian in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to extract a multiband image that crosses the international date line. Earth Engine will export the image  with the correct regional footprint, but any pixels that cross the antimeridian are empty. Sample code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6d652862d13bb38bcba5a8706b7e98e1) and also below

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[174.77387907584756, 39.08374600561265],
          [174.77387907584756, 29.215152961196402],
          [185.84809782584756, 29.215152961196402],
          [185.84809782584756, 39.08374600561265]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CDR/ATMOS_NEAR_SURFACE/V2')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-06-08', '2021-06-30'));
var air = dataset.select('wind_speed').toBands();

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: air,
  scale: 30000,
  region: roi
});
```